# how to read registry in java

Tags: java, binary, registry

how do you read registry keys in Java and then story that information into some kind of variable? furthermore, how do you create an installation binary so that you can distribute your product?

Comment: google "windows registry java" and possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627446/how-to-create-registry-key-through-java-program

Comment: Old but might work: http://www.trustice.com/java/jnireg/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java and many, many more.

Comment: The "furthermore ..." is a separate question, and should be asked separately. One question per question, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use java.util.prefs to read and write to the registry.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548307/working-with-windows-registry-using-java-util-prefs-preferences) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to read registry keys, but there are various third-party Windows-only libraries to do this. Of course, you should avoid it if you can -- why not write portable code that doesn't use the registry if you can? There's rarely a need.

Regarding installers, there are a number of products that do this: [InstallAnywhere](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installanywhere.htm), for example.